# how make a simple query from 2 queries

Tags: sql

I'm a bit stuck to getting a simple query from 2 queries and want to generate data like this

[Output example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeoKs.png)

#Query 1:

```
select b.number as ticket_id,
    d.name as reported_by,
    b.created as reported_date,
    f.topic as help_topic,
    c.subject,
    e.priority,
    h.created as l1_escalated_date,
    h.poster  as l1_escalated_by
from ost_staff a, 
    ost_ticket b, 
    ost_ticket__cdata c, 
    ost_user d, 
    ost_ticket_priority e,
    ost_help_topic f,
    ost_ticket_status g,
    ost_thread_entry h
where b.isanswered ='1' 
    and a.staff_id = b.staff_id 
    and b.ticket_id = c.ticket_id 
    and b.user_id = d.id
    and c.priority = e.priority_id 
    and b.topic_id = f.topic_id 
    and b.status_id = g.id 
    and b.ticket_id = h.thread_id 
    and (h.body like '%ESC1%' or h.body like '%RPN1%') 
group by b.number
```

#Query 2:

```
select b.number as ticket_id,
    d.name as reported_by,
    b.created as reported_date,
    f.topic as help_topic,
    c.subject,
    e.priority,
    h.created as l2_escalated_date,
    h.poster as l2_escalated_by
from ost_staff a, 
    ost_ticket b, 
    ost_ticket__cdata c, 
    ost_user d, 
    ost_ticket_priority e,
    ost_help_topic f,
    ost_ticket_status g,
    ost_thread_entry h
where b.isanswered ='1' 
    and a.staff_id = b.staff_id 
    and b.ticket_id = c.ticket_id 
    and b.user_id = d.id
    and c.priority = e.priority_id 
    and b.topic_id = f.topic_id 
    and b.status_id = g.id 
    and b.ticket_id = h.thread_id 
    and (h.body like '%ITL2%' or h.body like '%ITR2%') 
group by b.number
```

Main differences are

- Field aliases created for h.created and h.poster
- The h.body line in the WHERE clause

Comment: Just add in the extra conditions on `body`. That's the only thing I see not identical between the two.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using. In my answer I'm guessing MySQL. If it isn't, then my answer will be partly or completely wrong.

Comment: Then, don't link images. Instead, paste the table as text into your request. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

It isn't completely clear what you are trying to accomplish-- it would be very helpful in the future to post a reproducible test case.  As part of that, you really want to simplify the test case so that it shows the simplest query that demonstrates your problem.  You probably only need one table and a couple of columns to demonstrate the problem, for example.

It sounds like, however, you just want to do a `UNION` or a `UNION ALL` between the two queries.  Something like

```
SELECT 1 num, 'str' str
  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'bar' 
  FROM dual
```

will return a result set with two rows.  The difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is that `UNION` will eliminate any duplicate rows if both queries happen to return the same row.  To do that, however, `UNION` needs to incur the cost of sorting the results so `UNION ALL` will be more efficient if you know there won't be any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use UNION in this case as the column names are different but you can use CASE statement to fetch the data based on some condition.

```
SELECT b.number AS ticket_id
    ,d.name AS reported_by
    ,b.created AS reported_date
    ,f.topic AS help_topic
    ,c.subject
    ,e.priority
    ,l1_escalated_date = (CASE h.created 
        WHEN h.body LIKE '%ITL2%' OR h.body LIKE '%ITR2%'
            THEN h.created
        ELSE 
            NULL
        END  )
    ,l1_escalated_by =  (CASE h.poster
        WHEN h.body LIKE '%ITL2%' OR h.body LIKE '%ITR2%'
            THEN h.created
        ELSE 
            NULL
        END  )          
    ,l2_escalated_date = (CASE h.created 
        WHEN h.body LIKE '%ESC1%' OR h.body LIKE '%RPN1%'
            THEN h.created
        ELSE 
            NULL 
        END )
    ,l2_escalated_by =  (CASE h.poster
        WHEN h.body LIKE '%ESC1%' OR h.body LIKE '%RPN1%'
            THEN h.created
        ELSE 
            NULL 
        END )
FROM ost_staff a
    ,ost_ticket b
    ,ost_ticket__cdata c
    ,ost_user d
    ,ost_ticket_priority e
    ,ost_help_topic f
    ,ost_ticket_status g
    ,ost_thread_entry h
WHERE b.isanswered = '1'
    AND a.staff_id = b.staff_id
    AND b.ticket_id = c.ticket_id
    AND b.user_id = d.id
    AND c.priority = e.priority_id
    AND b.topic_id = f.topic_id
    AND b.status_id = g.id
    AND b.ticket_id = h.thread_id
    AND (
        h.body LIKE '%ITL2%'
        OR h.body LIKE '%ITR2%'
        OR h.body LIKE '%ESC1%'
        OR h.body LIKE '%RPN1%'
        )
GROUP BY b.number
```

Comment: Note - you (as well as the OP, as well as me in my now-deleted answer) have a `GROUP BY b.number`, but haven't specified what to do with other fields e.g., include them in the group by, or take an aggregate function like MAX().

Comment: Agreed GROUP BY or aggregate should be taken care in order to run the query. My bad  missed it

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two old queries here that were probably written in the 1980s, as can be seen from the ancient join syntax. Moreover, the author obfuscated things a little by applying generic alias names a, b, c, etc. rather than mnemonic ones. The two things make the queries prone to errors, so this is the first thing I'd care about.

In this process (or even before) we find out

- Table `ost_staff` is joined although it isn't used.
- Table `ost_ticket_status` is joined although it isn't used.
- Table `ost_ticket` has a column `ticket_id`, but we select a column `number` that we also call `ticket_id`. This is confusing or even a mistake.
- Both queries are invalid, as the `GROUP BY` clause doesn't match the selected columns. The data is aggreated by `ost_ticket.number`, but there can be multiple `ost_ticket__cdata`, multiple `ost_thread_entry`, and multiple `ost_ticket_priority` per `number`. The queries should both fail, but you still want them combined. Do they *run* in your DBMS?

You haven't tagged your DBMS, so I am guessing here. This may render my answer invalid. The only DBMS I know of that would run the queries and mutilate the results rather than throw an error are old MySQL versions. These silently applied `ANY_VALUE` on columns that didn't match the `GROUP BY` clause when not run in `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode. This means that in case of multiple matches, values got arbitrarily picked. If you are using an old MySQL version and really *want* this to happen, you should make this explicit by applying `ANY_VALUE` yourself.

Back to the original question: You want to show two different thread entries. For this to happen, join `ost_thread_entry` twice.

```
select
  t.number as ticket_id,
  u.name as reported_by,
  b.created as reported_date,
  ht.topic as help_topic,
  any_value(td.subject) as one_subject,
  any_value(tp.priority) as one_priority,
  any_value(te1.created) as one_l1_escalated_date,
  any_value(te1.poster) as one_l1_escalated_by,
  any_value(te2.created) as one_l2_escalated_date,
  any_value(te2.poster) as one_l2_escalated_by
from ost_ticket t
join ost_ticket__cdata td on td.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
join ost_user u on u.id = t.user_id
join ost_ticket_priority tp on tp.priority_id = td.priority
join ost_help_topic ht on ht.topic_id = t.topic_id
join ost_thread_entry te1 on te1.thread_id = t.ticket_id and (te1.body like '%ESC1%' or te1.body like '%RPN1%')
join ost_thread_entry te2 on te2.thread_id = t.ticket_id and (te2.body like '%ITL2%' or te2.body like '%ITR2%')
where t.isanswered = 1
group by t.number
order by t.number;
```

If you want to show tickets where you don't find both thread entries, you must change the inner joins to outer joins, i.e.

```
left join ost_thread_entry te1 on te1.thread_id = t.ticket_id and (te1.body like '%ESC1%' or te1.body like '%RPN1%')
left join ost_thread_entry te2 on te2.thread_id = t.ticket_id and (te2.body like '%ITL2%' or te2.body like '%ITR2%')
```